# Dependency inversion implementations for real time applications

Tags: c++, templates, dependency-injection, polymorphism, real-time

After reading Robert Martin's "Clean Architecture", I want to implement dependency inversion for computational heavy real time applications. More precisely:

- decoupling and independence of lowlevel IO modules
- no / minimal overhead
- static polymorphism

The use of interfaces / actract classes with virtual functions seems to add too much overhead (table lookups, ...) for real time scenarios.

**What implementations do you recommend?**

Regarding [Robert's example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zureA.jpg), I came up with a simple template-based approach:

```
#include "stdio.h"

class TestReader {
public:
    int read() {
        int input = 5;
        printf("Input:\t%d\n", input);
        return input;
    }
};

class ConsoleReader {
public:
    int read() {
        int input;
        printf("Enter Integer:\t");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        printf("Input:\t%d\n", input);
        return input;
    }
};

class ConsoleWriter {
public:
    void write(int input) {
        printf("Output:\t%d\n", input);
    }
};

template <typename TRead, typename TWrite>
class Encrypt {
public:
    void transform() {
        int input = IRead.read();

        printf("Encrypt...\n");
        int output = input + input;

        IWrite.write(output);
    };

private:
    TRead IRead;
    TWrite IWrite;
};


int main() {
    Encrypt<ConsoleReader, ConsoleWriter> b;
    b.transform();
}
```